# AJAX and Cross-Site Scripting to Read the Header

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, scripting, cross-domain

Help me understand AJAX and cross-site scripting a little better. Writing AJAX is fairly straight forward. If I want to asynchronously read HTTP header of a website, I'd do something like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('HEAD', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/', true);
req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
     if(req.status == 200)
      alert(req.responseText);
     else
      alert("Error loading page");
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

However, when I copy and paste this into a simple HTML page using notepad and try to run it locally, the request status doesn't seem to return 200. I am assuming this is due to cross-site scripting. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in that making requests across domains is not allowed unless you are using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS, http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).  CORS has a client-side and server side component.  On the client side, the request looks mostly like a regular XmlHttpRequest, except you have a few other properties and handlers you can configure.  On the server, the response will need to emit some special http headers.  This article gives a good breakdown of how CORS works on the client and server: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to try and make a local PHP file which acts like a gateway:

```
<?php
  echo get_headers($_GET['url']);
?>
```

Then, perform a `GET` request with the url of your target site as the parameter, and parse the `.responseText` of *that* request to determine the response header of your original.

I don't think it's possible with *pure* JS, so you'll have to use some serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of "locally":

- Using a local server (http://localhost/)
- Accessing HTML file directly (file:///C:\a\b\c.html)

AJAX won't work, ever, in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an ajax request to http://stackoverflow.com if your page is being served on http://localhost/...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests